# android popup window call from oncreate

Tags: android, popupwindow

```
private void loadingPopup() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
          View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_dialog, null);

        PopupWindow windows = new PopupWindow(layout , 300,300,true);
       windows.setFocusable(false);
          windows.setTouchable(true); 
          windows.setOutsideTouchable(true);
          windows.showAtLocation(layout,Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

}
```

when invoke the method `loadingPopup()` from `oncreate()` an exception accrued .. please can you help me

Comment: can you post the log cat?

Comment: you need to post what the exception is?

Comment: 02-06 15:36:12.140: E/AndroidRuntime(17670):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
02-06 15:36:12.140: E/AndroidRuntime(17670):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
02-06 15:36:12.140: E/AndroidRuntime(17670):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 15:36:12.140: E/AndroidRuntime(17670): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: @abed : post your full Activity code

Comment: my question about how can call pop up window without button ( i want on activity load)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are trying to show the pop-up window even before the activity window has been displayed.
With the help of post method we can wait until all necessary start up life cycle methods get completed.

Try this :

```
private void loadingPopup() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_dialog, null);

    final PopupWindow windows = new PopupWindow(layout , 300,300,true);
    windows.setFocusable(false);
    windows.setTouchable(true); 
    windows.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    layout.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            windows.showAtLocation(layout,Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }
    });
}
```